# Keep css from changing after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have a different couple of themes on my website, and there is a dropdown menu with buttons where you can switch your theme. Here is how I have it set up:

```
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  }
</script>
```

Then here's the button this is attached to:

```
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('style-green.min.css')">Green Theme</button>
```

This works great; however, whenever I hit the refresh button on my screen, it switches back to the original stylesheet that was first attached to the page. I want it to keep whatever stylesheet it was switched to on refresh. How do I do this? Is there something I can add to my  tag that will let me store some type of session/data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage to this;

```html
<script>
 function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
   localStorage.setItem('style', sheet);
   document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
 }
 
 function applyStyleSheet() {
   // restore style
   const sheet = localStorage.getItem('style') || 'style-green.min.css';
   document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
 }
 
 applyStyleSheet();

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks as well, appreciate the detail - this is super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `href` in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

To save it, you can use:

```
localStorage.setItem('csshref', href);
```

And on page load, you can do:

```
swapStylesheet(localStorage.getItem('csshref'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try it out :)

Comment: @jchillin111 No problem. If it answers your question, please consider accepting